# Generalise heterogeneous tuple of variable-length MVector's to a variable number of MVector's

Tags: julia

Is there a way to create a parametric type which represents a heterogeneous tuple of variable length, where each element of the tuple is a MVector, such that the MVector's can have different length but they contain the same numerical type. So in pseudo code I would like to have something like this:

```
using StaticArrays

struct MyType{T, N1, N2, N3, ...}
    data::Tuple{MVector{N1, T}, MVector{N2, T}, MVector{N3, T}, ...}
end
```

I can of course make a more specific type like:

```
struct MyType3{T, N1, N2, N3}
    data::Tuple{MVector{N1, T}, MVector{N2, T}, MVector{N3, T}}
end
```

But I would like to generalise to an tuple of arbitrary length.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the "variadic type arguments" `N1`...`Nk` explicitely, you can use a tuple of `Vararg` of some `UnionAll` types:

```
julia> MyType3{T} = Tuple{Vararg{MVector{M, <:T} where M}}
Tuple{Vararg{MArray{Tuple{M},#s14,1,M} where #s14<:T where M,N} where N} where T

julia> (MVector{2}([1,2]), MVector{3}([1,2,3])) isa MyType3{Int}
true

julia> (MVector{2}([1,2]), MVector{3}([1,2,3])) isa MyType3{Number}
true

julia> (MVector{2}([1,2]), MVector{3}([1,2,3])) isa MyType3{String}
false

julia> (MVector{2}([1,2]), MVector{3}([1,2,3])) isa MyType3
true

julia> (MVector{2}(["a", "b"]), MVector{3}([1,2,3])) isa MyType3
true
```

Or maybe like this, where you have an explicit tuple of the size types:

```
julia> struct MyType7{T, Ns<:Tuple, D}
           data::D
           function MyType7(vecs::Vararg{MVector{M, T} where M}) where {T}
               Ns = [typeof(v).parameters[4] for v in vecs]
               new{T, Tuple{Ns...}, typeof(vecs)}(vecs)
           end
       end

julia> MyType7(MVector{2}([1,2]), MVector{3}([1,2,3]))
MyType7{Int64,Tuple{2,3},Tuple{MArray{Tuple{2},Int64,1,2},MArray{Tuple{3},Int64,1,3}}}(([1, 2], [1, 2, 3]))

julia> typeof(ans)
MyType7{Int64,Tuple{2,3},Tuple{MArray{Tuple{2},Int64,1,2},MArray{Tuple{3},Int64,1,3}}}
```

But this is now a kind of a hack, since we use `parameters` to reflect on the type arguments at runtime.  If you use this variant, be sure to know what you're doing (which I wouldn't quite say about myself), and to benchmark it (or maybe make it `@generate`d?).

Comment: And in case I do need `N1`...`Nk`? Is there a way?

Comment: I think you would have to construct a tuple of singleton types (`Tuple{2,3}` in this case), since there's no other way to get variadic type arguments for custom types. And then provide a (possibly generated) inner constructor to convert that into the type you need. I'll have to think about it.